# Get Odd Length Palindrome

Tags: python, palindrome

I'm trying to find the longest odd length palindrome, but the code I've written isn't giving me the full palindrome, just part of it. Any help would be great!

```
def get_odd_palindrome_at(s, index):
    ''' (str, int) -> str

    > get_odd_palindrome_at('tbababt', 3)
    'tbababt'
    > get_odd_palindrome_at('color', 2)
    'olo'
    '''

    palindrome = s[index]
    i = index

    for char in s:
        if s[i - 1] == s[i + 1]:
            palindrome = s[i - 1] + palindrome + s[i + 1]
            i = i + 1

    return palindrome
```

Comment: I think you want `s[index - i]` and `s[index + i]`, otherwise `i = i + 1` always move 'i' to the right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `i` the distance from the `index` and make sure not to loop out of bounds. Finally, only build the result string when you have found the final value of `i`. There is no use in doing it in every iteration:

```
def get_odd_palindrome_at(s, index):
    for i in range(1, index+1):
        if index + i >= len(s) or s[index - i] != s[index + i]:
            i -= 1
            break

    return s[index-i:index+i+1]
```

Alternatively, you could use two variables, which simplifies the code a bit:

```
def get_odd_palindrome_at(s, index):
    i = index
    j = index
    while i >= 0 and j < len(s) and s[i] == s[j]:
        i -= 1
        j += 1

    return s[i+1:j]
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is complete working code which cover even/odd and other factors **

```
    public class NextSmallestPalindrome {

    static void utilityFunction(int array[], int n)  
    { 
    int mid = n / 2; 
        int i = mid - 1; 
        int j = (n % 2 == 0) ? mid : mid + 1; 
        boolean leftsmaller = false; 
  
        while (i >= 0 && array[i] == array[j])  
        { 
            i--; 
            j++; 
        } 
          
        if (i < 0 || array[i] < array[j])  
        { 
        leftsmaller = true; 
        } 
          
        while (i >= 0)  
        { 
        array[j++] = array[i--];  //code to swap
        } 
    
        if (leftsmaller)  
    { 
            int carry = 1; 
          
            if (n % 2 == 1) { 
                array[mid] += 1; 
                carry = array[mid] / 10; 
                array[mid] %= 10; 
        } 
            i = mid - 1; 
            j = (n % 2 == 0 ? mid : mid + 1); 
              
            while (i >= 0 && carry>0)   
            { 
                array[i] = array[i] + carry; 
            carry = array[i] / 10; 
                array[i] %= 10; 
                array[j] = array[i];
                i--; 
                j++; 
            } 
  
        } 
} 
  
    static void nextPalindromeProblem(int array[], int n)  
    { 
        System.out.println("Next Palindrome is:"); 
          
        if (isAll9(array, n)) { 
            System.out.print("1"); 
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) 
            System.out.print("0"); 
            System.out.println("1"); 
  
        } 
      
        else { 
            utilityFunction(array, n); 
            printarray(array); 
        } 
    } 

    static boolean isAll9(int array[], int n) { 
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
            if (array[i] != 9) 
                return false; 
        return true; 
} 
  
    static void printarray(int array[]) { 
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
        System.out.print(array[i]); 
        System.out.println(); 
    } 
  
    public static void main(String[] args)  
    { 
    int array[] = { 2, 8, 3, 8, 4, 9}; 
        nextPalindromeProblem(array, array.length); 
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You move `i` every time, so you don't extend the index to both direction, but move your 3-letters-circle to the right every time. You need to keep the *original* index, and every time add or substruct equal increasing amount of index from the *original* index:

```
How you want it to be:

c o l o r
  - i -
-   i   -

How it's doing:

c o l o r
  - i -
    - i -
```

So practically just save the index, and increment the margin. Also, you want to iterate only `index` margins, not the string, so:

```
def get_odd_palindrome_at (s, index):

    palindrome = s[index]

    for i in range(index):
        if s[index - i] == s[index + i]:
            palindrome = s[index - i] + palindrome + s[index + i]
        else:
            break

    return palindrome
```