# Problems finding 3-digit Palindrom

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

I cant figure out how to get this palindrom code working.

The problem might be the wrong splitting of the string?
Thanks for help!

```
using System;
class Start
{

static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(FindPalindroms());
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static bool IsPalindrom(int numb)
{
    string sub1 = "";
    string sub2 = "";
    string productString = "";

    productString = Convert.ToString(numb);
    sub1 = productString.Substring(0, productString.Length / 2);
    sub2 = productString.Substring(productString.Length / 2, productString.Length / 2);
    sub2 = Reverse(sub2);

    if (sub1.Equals(sub2))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
static bool FindPalindroms()
{
    int product = 0;
    for (int i = 100; i < 999; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 100; j < 999; j++)
        {
            product = i * j;

            if (IsPalindrom(product))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Palindrom found: " + product);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
public static string Reverse(string s)
{
    char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(charArray);
    return new string(charArray);
}
}
```

The output of this code is(not the full output):

Palindrom found: 11110

Palindrom found: 22220

Palindrom found: 33330

Palindrom found: 44440

Comment: I suggest you may need to learn how to break point your code, you will figure this out quickly once you do

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
The problem is likely in `IsPalindrome`.  For now, remove `Main`; replace `FindPalindrome` with a short loop of test numbers.  Trace the execution.  Post that.

Comment: Learning to debug code is an important skill to learn. I suggest reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips to get you started.

Comment: Since this is probably homework, I'd like to also encourage you to learn to use a debugger.

I'm not one of those people, especially when I was newer to writing code, who can write it perfect the first time every time. I learned how to use a debugger early in college, and it helped me tremendously.

Comment: And until you're familiar with integer division, `productString.Length / 2` may not be what you think it will be when `Length` is an odd number. Set a breakpoint on `if (sub1.Equals(sub2))` and notice the values of `sub1` and `sub2` when `product.Length == 5`.

Comment: Alright, I will look that debug guide up. Thanks for all your suggestions..

Comment: Answer is here for palindrom with even and odd digit : https://stackoverflow.com/a/71363528/15117824

Answer (score 0):

With Linq

```
public static bool IsPalindrome(string str)
{
    return String.Compare(str, new string(Enumerable.Range(1, str.Length).Select(i => str[str.Length - i ]).ToArray())) == 0;
}
```

Without Linq

```
public static bool IsPalindrome2(string str)
{
    var isPalindrome = true;
    for (int i=0; i<str.Length ; i++)
    {
        if ( str[i] != str[str.Length -i -1])
        {
            isPalindrome = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return isPalindrome;
}
```

**Edit** In your case, you are dividing string length into half. let say you have 5 digit palindrome. You are dividing Length of palindrome which is 5 over 2 = 2, after that you are getting substring of it

```
len = str.Length  / 2 // 5/2 = 2 
part1 = str.substr(0,2);
part2 = str.substr(2,2); // this part is wrong for 5 digit number
```

for 4 digit number

```
len = str.Length  / 2 // 4/2 = 2 
part1 = str.substr(0,2);
part2 = str.substr(2,2); // now it is giving correct result.
```

check the below code for solution

```
static bool IsPalindrom(int numb)
{
    var productString = Convert.ToString(numb);
    var sub1 = productString.Substring(0, productString.Length / 2);
    var sub2 = new string(productString.Substring(productString.Length / 2 + (productString.Length % 2 == 1 ? 1 : 0), productString.Length / 2).Reverse().ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine(sub1);
    Console.WriteLine(sub2);

    return sub1.Equals(sub2);
}
```

Comment: This may be the solution, but it in no way helps the user in anyway apart from writing their code. For this to be useful, why not explain the problem with their current code

Comment: The explaination is added.. Please feel free to check it again. Thank you for your comment